# How to download ubuntu sdk documentations for offline reading?

Tags: documentation, ubuntu-sdk

Rather than *saving each and every page separately* (coz that would be a tedious job) I want to know if there is a **single pdf file** or a file in any other format of those huge documentations that I could download in single click?

I know there are always some people out there who do such jobs. I don't have permanent Internet connection nor never-ending free time to go online every time,that's why I'll prefer **offline documentation.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the `ubuntu-ui-toolkit-doc` package, if it isn't installed already.  Then you'll have a copy of the SDK documentation at file:///usr/share/ubuntu-ui-toolkit/doc/html/overview-ubuntu-sdk.html

This is a general pattern in Linux packaging: the documentation for a library is available in a `*-doc` package, just like header files come in the `*-dev` package.

Answer (score 0):

scrapbook firefox addon is amasing, try it.